# The most efficient way to move psql databases

Tags: sql, pg-dump

What is the most efficient, secure way to pipe the contents of a postgresSQL database into a compressed tarfile, then copy to another machine?

This would be used for localhosting development, or backing up to a remote server, using *nix based machines at both ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pg_dump is indeed the proper solution. Be sure to read the man page. In Espo's example, some options are questionable (-x and -D) and may not suit you.

As with every other database manipulation, test a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-back-up-a-web-server/) has a complete backup script for a webserver, including the pg_dump output.

Here is the syntax it uses:

```
BACKUP="/backup/$NOW"
PFILE="$(hostname).$(date +'%T').pg.sql.gz"
PGSQLUSER="vivek"
PGDUMP="/usr/bin/pg_dump"

$PGDUMP -x -D -U${PGSQLUSER} | $GZIP -c > ${BACKUP}/${PFILE}
```

After you have gzipped it, you can transfer it to the other server with [scp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy), [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) or [nfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_file_system) depending on your network and services.